# How to make a widget using electron that sticks to bottom and is still usable

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm trying to make a widget for desktop using electron, I read about the `type: desktop` way of setting the browser window to be at the bottom-most level always, but it can't handle any events then and thereby can only be used for widgets that do not require user interaction. 
Is there any way to keep it at the bottom and the user can still interact with it (like make it draggable)?